# I'm getting an error whenever, I click sign in. in magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I'm having an error messages everytime i click sign in. in my Magento 2 site.

Here's the error message attached:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it happened because name of Email and Password fields are wrong. They must be such as this:

```
<input name="login[username]"  .. >
<input name="login[password]" .. >
```

It because in file `CheckUserLoginObserver.php` at line 79-80 is this code:

```
$loginParams = $controller->getRequest()->getPost('login');
$login = array_key_exists('username', $loginParams) ? $loginParams['username'] : null;
```

And if you have this error it means that $loginParams is null and no request with such parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked the customer login form. and look through its codes. I find the the fields are ok like you've mentioned above.

<input name="login[username]"  .. >
<input name="login[password]" .. >

That's the format in my customer login form

Comment: I'm reproduce this when for form set method "get". Or maybe your form has no parameter 'method'

Comment: <form class="form form-login"
              action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>"
              method="post" 

Do you mean that lines? It has a method

Comment: Sorry, I have no more ideas..

Comment: Thanks for the effort Irop. It's ok maybe someone can answer my question.